# How to parse multiple nested JSON keys without an external recursive function?

Tags: python, json, api, nested, discord

I'm working on a Discord Bot which parses an API, formats and returns the data.
There are nested keys that I need to parse, in particularly the "current", "today", "day30", "day90", and "day180" keys, and cannot find a straight forward way to do so.
Here's the JSON Data:

```
{
  "item": {
    "icon": "url_removed_for_obscurity",
    "icon_large": "url_removed_for_obscurity",
    "id": 859,
    "type": "Default",
    "typeIcon": "url_removed_for_obscurity",
    "name": "Example Item",
    "description": "Example Item Description",
    "current": {
      "trend": "neutral",
      "price": "1,210"
    },
    "today": {
      "trend": "negative",
      "price": "- 16"
    },
    "members": "true",
    "day30": {
      "trend": "negative",
      "change": "-4.0%"
    },
    "day90": {
      "trend": "negative",
      "change": "-8.0%"
    },
    "day180": {
      "trend": "negative",
      "change": "-3.0%"
    }
  }
}
```

This works as intended:

```
item_desc = '';
current_vals = ''; todays_vals = ''; day30_vals = ''; day90_vals = ''; day180_vals = ''
current_trend = ''; todays_trend = ''; day30_trend = ''; day90_trend = ''; day180_trend = '';

get_item_data = requests.get(item_endpoint).json()

for key, val in get_item_data.items():
        if(query_id == str(val['id'])):
            #print('[Debug] Found Item Through API...')
            if('description' in val):
                item_desc = str(val['description'])
                await context.send(item_desc)
            if('current' in val):
                current_vals = str(val['current'])
                await context.send(current_vals)
            if('today' in val):
                todays_vals = str(val['today'])
                await context.send(todays_vals)
            if('day30' in val):
                day30_vals = str(val['day30'])
                await context.send(day30_vals)
            if('day90' in val):
                day90_vals = str(val['day90'])
                await context.send(day90_vals)
            if('day180' in val):
                day180_vals = str(val['day180'])
                await context.send(day180_vals)
            break
```

And outputs:

```
Example Item Description
{'trend': 'neutral', 'price': '1,210'}
{'trend': 'negative', 'price': '- 16'}
{'trend': 'negative', 'change': '-4.0%'}
{'trend': 'negative', 'change': '-8.0%'}
{'trend': 'negative', 'change': '-3.0%'}
```

I know I need to do something like:

```
current_trend = ''; todays_trend = ''; day30_trend = ''; day90_trend = ''; day180_trend = '';
            if('current' in val):
                current_vals = str(val['current'])
                parse_current_vals = json.loads(current_vals)
                if('trend' in parse_current_vals.items()):
                    current_trend = str(parse_current_vals['trend'])
                    await context.send(current_trend)
etc
```

I'd like it to simply return

```
negative
```

```
neutral
```

or

```
positive
```

It currently returns nothing, because I clearly am not parsing correctly.
I've tried many different variations of the above to no avail. The last couple of hours of googling and trial/error has turned me here for advice. Any and all input is welcome and appreciated.

Comment: What is your expected output? and how it is different from the output you are getting?

Comment: @deadshot Edited accordingly.

Comment: it still not clear

Comment: I'd like it to simply output "negative" "neutral" or "positive". It currently outputs nothing as it sits, because I know I am not going about it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

```
 data = {
  "item": {
    "icon": "url_removed_for_obscurity",
    "icon_large": "url_removed_for_obscurity",
    "id": 859,
    "type": "Default",
    "typeIcon": "url_removed_for_obscurity",
    "name": "Example Item",
    "description": "Example Item Description",
    "current": {
      "trend": "neutral",
      "price": "1210"
    },
    "today": {
      "trend": "negative",
      "price": "-16"
    },
    "members": "true",
    "day30": {
      "trend": "negative",
      "change": "-4.0%"
    },
    "day90": {
      "trend": "negative",
      "change": "-8.0%"
    },
    "day180": {
      "trend": "negative",
      "change": "-3.0%"
    }
  }
}
def as_float(val):
    value = val.strip()
    if value.endswith('%'):
        value = value[:-1]
    value = value.replace(',','')
    return float(value)
collected_trends = []
interesting_keys = {'day30','today','current'}
for key in interesting_keys:
    entry = data['item'][key]
    num = entry['change'] if 'change' in entry else entry['price']
    collected_trends.append([entry['trend'],as_float(num)])
print(collected_trends)
```

output

```
[['neutral', 1210.0], ['negative', -4.0], ['negative', -16.0]]
```

Comment: So you would recommend storing the entire query in a variable, and parsing system-side instead of utilizing .items() against my get request?

Comment: Yes .. maintain a list/set of the "interesting keys" and read their values directly.

Comment: This returns the same that my function already does ```[{'trend': 'negative', 'change': '-4.0%'}, {'trend': 'negative', 'price': '- 16'}]``` Where I'm having the issue is getting the value "negative" from the "trend" key. (And then the value from the price key) @balderman

Comment: @D7L6-D6L7 code was modified. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: I am seeing that "trend" and "price" are not actually keys. How would you recommend parsing the output of your code and scraping for the trend and numerical price values...?

Comment: some of the numbers contain % and some not. so your parsing should be aware of that.

Comment: some of the numbers contain % and some not. so your parsing should be aware of that.

Comment: @D7L6-D6L7 code was updated in order to handle the numbers

Comment: Hi. Not sure I understand...if you are happy with my answer - feel free to vote up

Comment: I did, but I am a new member so it doesn't count. I need to reassign the values held in the collected_trends array to my global variables. current_trend/today_trend etc.

Comment: OK. Try to use a dict. Use the interesting keys as the dict keys and the collected trends as the dict value

Comment: Great to hear that.